# Java Service require a bean (Interface)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

have anyone a idea why the Service is asking for a bean ? I'm building a small microservice with a Article- and Authorservice. Where is the issue here ?

I'm using feign-reactor-spring-cloud-starter dependency for the communication between the services.

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ArticleService{

    private final IArticleRepository articleRepository;
    private final IAuthorResponse authorResponse;

    public Mono<ArticleRequest> createArticle(
            ArticleRequest articleRequest,
            String authorEmail
    ){
        Mono<AuthorResponse> requestedAuthor = authorResponse
                .getAuthorByEmail(authorEmail)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new BadRequestException(valueOf(AUTHOR_NOT_FOUND))))
                .map(author -> new AuthorResponse(
                        author.firstName(),
                        author.lastName(),
                        author.email()))
                .log();

        Article articleModel = Article.builder()
                    .articleId(UUID.randomUUID())
                    .articleTitle(articleRequest.title())
                    .articleContent(articleRequest.content())
                    .publishedAt(IDateTimeCreator.createDateTime())
                    .authorEmail(requestedAuthor.map(AuthorResponse::email).block()) //TODO: implement current loggedIn AuthorEmail
                    .build();

        return articleRepository
                .existsArticleByAuthorEmailAndAndArticleTitle(
                        articleModel.getAuthorEmail(),
                        articleModel.getArticleTitle())
                .flatMap(exists -> {
                    if (exists) {
                        return Mono.error(
                                new BadRequestException(valueOf(ARTICLE_ALREADY_EXISTS)));
                    } else {
                        return articleRepository
                                .save(articleModel)
                                .map(article -> new ArticleRequest(
                                        article.getArticleTitle(),
                                        article.getArticleContent()))
                                .log();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
@ReactiveFeignClient(name = "authorservice", configuration = ReactiveFeignConfig.class)
public interface IAuthorResponse {
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/v1/author/{authorEmail}")
    Mono<AuthorResponse> getAuthorByEmail(@PathVariable("authorEmail") String authorEmail);
}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveFeignConfig {
    @Bean
    public ReactiveLoggerListener loggerListener(){
        return new DefaultReactiveLogger(Clock.systemUTC(), LoggerFactory.getLogger("articleservice"));
    }
    // Here we specify our Exception between the articleservice and authorservice
    @Bean
    public ReactiveStatusHandler reactiveStatusHandler() {
        return ReactiveStatusHandlers.throwOnStatus(
                (status) -> (status == 500),
                (methodKey, response) ->
                        new RetryableException(
                                response.status(),
                                "Failed. The ArticleService couldn't reach the Authorservice. Please try again!",
                                null,
                                Date.from(Instant.EPOCH),
                                null));
    }
    // In case of an error such as a simple timeout occurred, we've the opportunity with this methode to try again.
    @Bean
    public ReactiveRetryPolicy reactiveRetryPolicy() {
        return BasicReactiveRetryPolicy.retryWithBackoff(3, 2500);
    }
}
```

This is a part of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.salenaluu</groupId>
        <artifactId>clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Interface is in a seperate module with no main class.

Mainclass:

```
@EnableReactiveFeignClients(basePackages = "com.salenaluu.clients}")
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ArticleServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ArticleServiceApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

Message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in ...ArticleService required a bean of type '....IAuthorResponse' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '....IAuthorResponse' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: based on the code above, `ArticleService` depends on an instance of `IAuthorResponse`. Spring will try to inject an instance via your constructor. If there is no instance of `IAuthorResponse` in the `ApplicationContext`, the startup of your application will fail with the message above. Do you have an implementation of `IAuthorResponse` (assuming it's an interface)?

Comment: Yes it's an Interface :). I tried to make it in the Configuration, but it didn't solved the issue. Mabye my code was wrong written there :)

Comment: do you provide an implementation of that interface? Is that implementation a spring managed bean?

Comment: What do you mean exactlly ? I created this repo... But I didn't know how to solve it correctly.

Comment: do you have your main class or configuration class annotated with `@EnableReactiveFeignClients` ?

Comment: Hi yes :) @EnableReactiveFeignClients(basePackages = "...") is there

Comment: that is all you should need to get this to work. Can you share the code for your main class so we can see the annotations being applied? Also, does the `basePackages` match the name of your package structure?

Comment: I have now updated it